# Android Flash support

Tags: android, flash

Can Android applications can use flash content in them?

Answer (score 2):

From android 2.2 (Froyo) flash is supported.

If you want to use it in an app you could use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can instantiate a web browser object or similar, and have that open a Flash swf file from a website or local storage, so yeah, in theory you could have flash inside your app...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that AIR is supported by Android now too.

http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2010/04/adobe_air_applications_for_and.html